# Is it possible to define JDK path in settings.gradle?

Tags: gradle

I know you can define the JDK path in a build.gradle file with:

```
compileJava.options.fork = true
compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = '/path_to_javac'
```

I was wondering if you could do something similar in the settings.gradle file?

Comment: What version of Gradle

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, our Gradle version is 6.9.1